# watson assistant can't display image from my computer

Tags: watson-assistant

okay i'm building a  chatbot. I created a new node and assign its response type to "image", but watson assistant can't display image directly from my computer.

Warning: Cannot load image from url: C:\Users\R.I.S.E\Documents\passport\me.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's cool that you're working on a chatbot! The problem you're running into doesn't have much to do with Watson Assistant, though; you've bumped into a fundamental security design with browsers and web services. That is, unless you explicitly upload an image to a third party service, that service can't access any data on your local computer (which is a good thing, where security is concerned).

Watson Assistant doesn't accept image uploads, so you need to host your image somewhere and then use its URL in the dialog response.

Try using a service like [Imgur](https://imgur.com) to upload your image, then get the link for it (you can usually right-click on the image and choose something like "copy image address") and use that URL in your bot's response. That should work!

Comment: Thank you. I sincerely do appreciate.